# Why is my vba code not applying to all worksheets?

Tags: excel, vba

I need to enter formulas into column L and M if column B is not empty.

My code works on the active worksheet I am running but it won't fill out the others. I have 23 worksheets with the same template in one workbook.

Am I not including the R1C1 lines (`Cells(i, 12).FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-1]-rc[-2]"`) within the `With` statements somehow?

```
Sub forEachWs_Format_ForecastingTemplate()

    Dim ws As Worksheet

    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        Call Format_ForecastingTemplate_analysis_formulas(ws)
    Next
End Sub


Sub Format_ForecastingTemplate_analysis_formulas(ws As Worksheet)

    Dim cell As Range
    Dim N As Long
    Dim i As Long

    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 7 To N
        If ws.Cells(i, 2) <> "" Then
            Cells(i, 12).FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-1]-rc[-2]"
            Cells(i, 13).FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-2]-rc[-4]"
            With Range(ws.Cells(i, 12), ws.Cells(i, 13))
                .NumberFormat = "_(* #,##0_);_(* (#,##0);_(* ""-""??_);_(@_)"
            End With
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: You are not qualifying all your ranges with `ws` so the macro defaults to the activeSheet

Comment: You pass `ws As Worksheet` as a parameter to your sub, but then ignore it for most of the code.

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad Duuuuuuude. I'm new to vba but that is such a simple mistake.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Does the `ImplicitActiveSheetReference` take into account that `Cells` means `Me.Cells` when used from a worksheet module?

Comment: @GSerg it should, yes =)

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Then the description on that page should probably be updated :)

Comment: @GSerg just tested it - it actually doesn't (there's an open issue for it), but that's because we're resolving to a member call against `_Global`, because the resolver isn't correctly identifying document modules' "base class" (i.e. `Sheet1` "is a" `Worksheet`). When I get the tests passing on my pending PR, that will be fixed and I'll definitely revisit the inspections' xml-doc accordingly - thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct answer by @cybernetic.nomad in comments.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following instead:

```
Sub forEachWs_Format_ForecastingTemplate()

    Dim ws As Worksheet

    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        Call Format_ForecastingTemplate_analysis_formulas(ws)
    Next
End Sub


Sub Format_ForecastingTemplate_analysis_formulas(ws As Worksheet)
with ws
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim N As Long
    Dim i As Long

    N = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 7 To N
        If .Cells(i, 2) <> "" Then
            .Cells(i, 12).FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-1]-rc[-2]"
            .Cells(i, 13).FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-2]-rc[-4]"
            With Range(.Cells(i, 12), .Cells(i, 13))
                .NumberFormat = "_(* #,##0_);_(* (#,##0);_(* ""-""??_);_(@_)"
            End With
        End If
    Next
end with
End Sub
```

Comment: Would help to add an explanation

Comment: He just referenced the selected ws using ```With ws```. I didn't do that before so the ```Cells``` referenced the active ws.

Comment: `With Range(` is implicitly using whatever worksheet happens-to-be active at the time. You likely want to use `With .Range(` instead, noting the `.` which is accessing the `ws` object you passed in.